# Regular point of a map in algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

What is the correct definition of a regular point of a map in algebraic geometry?

More specifically, let $f:X\to Y$ be a map of varieties with $f(p) = q$, and let $Z=f^{-1}(q)$.  Let $\hat{X}$ be the formal completion of $X$ at $p$, $\hat{Y}$ the formal completion of $Y$ at $q$, and $\hat{Z}$ the formal completion of $Z$ at $p$.
I would like a nice condition on $f$ that implies that 
$$\hat{X}\cong \hat{Y}\times\hat{Z}.$$
Intuitively, this should be an algebraic version of the statement that $p$ is a regular point of $f$.

I do not want to make any smoothness assumptions about $X$ or $Z$.  In particular, if $X = Y \times Z$ and $f$ is the projection onto $Y$, then every point of $Y\times Z$ should be a regular point of $f$, even if $Z$ is singular.  (The conclusion about formal neighborhoods is obviously true in this trivial case!)

Comment: A necessary condition should be that for each formal isomorphism class of point, the locus in $X$ of points $p$ such that isomorphism class of $f^{-1}(f(p))$ at $p$ is that isomorphism class should be smooth over $Y$. I'm not sure if that's sufficient.

Comment: Are you sure this condition is what you want? Take $Y= \operatorname{Spec} k[t]$ and $X= \operatorname{Spec} k[x,y,t]/(xy(x-y)(x-ty))$ and $f: X \to Y$ the obvious map. Then none of the fibers are formally isomorphic to their neighbors near $0$, so $f$ is not regular at $0$ for any $t$, even though for most practical purposes this map is regular away from $t=0,1,\infty$. You could consider weakening the definition.

Comment: @WillSawin: I'm not sure that I understand your example.  We have $Y = \mathbb{A}^1$, and for all $q\in\mathbb{A}^1\smallsetminus\{0,1\}$, $Z$ is a union of four lines, glued at the origin.  I agree that $(0,0,q)$ feels like it should be a regular point of $f$, and it seems to me that the formal completion of $X$ at $(0,0,q)$ does look like the product of the formal completion of $Z$ at 0 and the formal completion of $\mathbb{A}^1$ at $q$.  Is this not the case?

Comment: It is not the case. Take any two elements of the formal completion that generate the maximal ideal $(x,y)$. They will satisfy a polynomial relation of degree $4$. The leading term will be, up to a linear change of coordinates, equal to $xy(x-y)(x-ty)$. The action of $GL_2$ on binary quartic polynomials has a nontrivial invariant, the $j$ invariant, which is a nonconstant function of $t$, and so no change of variables can make this a constant family.

Comment: Okay, that's an interesting example.  I guess you've convinced me that the isomorphism I requested will be less common than I had thought.  For what it's worth, the conclusion that I *really* care about is that the cohomology of the stalk of $IC_X$ at $p$ agrees with the cohomology of the stalk of $IC_Y$ at $q$ times the cohomology of the stalk of $IC_Z$ at $p$.  Perhaps my hope for an actual formal trivialization of $\,f$ near $p$ is unrealistic.